# Move selected sentence, word left/right by equivalent unit?

Tags: text-editing, region

More broadly, should work by the selected semantic unit (incl. paragraphs in text mode, and the relevant units in other modes). I.e., if a sentence is selected, then the notional "move-left" would move the selected sentence to before the preceding sentence; if a word is selected, then analogously, move the selected word to before the preceding *word*.

The solution is intended to be used in combination with expand-region https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el

smart-shift is somewhat similar, but moves the selection by a character at a time.

transpose-words and transpose-sentences are also similar but require a negative argument to move "to the left"; and they are distinct functions, while I would like to have a single function that understands its context, i.e. whether a word, a sentence, etc. is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe drag-stuff.el is what you're looking for.

Drag Stuff is a minor mode for Emacs that makes it possible to drag stuff (words, region, lines) around in Emacs. See https://github.com/rejeep/drag-stuff.el